# Why is the same SSIM metric giving different values for the same 2 images?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

Summary: for the same 2 images, my implementation of the SSIM metric & someone else's implementation give two different SSIM scores. Trying to understand why.

So, I created an ssim function that takes in 2 images' numpy array data of size (64,128,1) and size 8192. Then, it uses python's structural similarity function to calculate the similarity score between the two images (**from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim**)

My ssim function is shown below:

```
def ssim_mine(img_1,img_2): 
    img_1_array=np.array([])
    img_2_array=np.array([])
    
    for i in range(len(img_1)):   
        img_1_trans=np.transpose(img_1[i])
        img_1_array=np.append(img_1_array,img_1_trans)

        img_2_trans=np.transpose(img_2[i])
        img_2_array=np.append(img_2_array,img_2_trans)
    print(img_1_array.size)
    dist = ssim(img_1_array, img_2_array)
    return dist
```

From this [python package](https://github.com/up42/image-similarity-measures/blob/master/image_similarity_measures/quality_metrics.py) , I found the following ssim function that takes in images as .png or .jpg files. For instance,

```
in_img2 = cv2.imread('img2.png')
out_ssim = ssim_github(in_img1, in_img2)
```

This is their ssim function (ssim_github below):

```
def _assert_image_shapes_equal(org_img: np.ndarray, pred_img: np.ndarray, metric: str):
    # shape of the image should be like this (rows, cols, bands)
    # Please note that: The interpretation of a 3-dimension array read from rasterio is: (bands, rows, columns) while
    # image processing software like scikit-image, pillow and matplotlib are generally ordered: (rows, columns, bands)
    # in order efficiently swap the axis order one can use reshape_as_raster, reshape_as_image from rasterio.plot
    msg = (
        f"Cannot calculate {metric}. Input shapes not identical. y_true shape ="
        f"{str(org_img.shape)}, y_pred shape = {str(pred_img.shape)}"
    )

    assert org_img.shape == pred_img.shape, msg

def ssim_github(org_img: np.ndarray, pred_img: np.ndarray, max_p: int = 4095) -> float:
    """
    Structural Simularity Index
    """
    _assert_image_shapes_equal(org_img, pred_img, "SSIM")

    return ssim(org_img, pred_img, data_range=max_p, multichannel=True)
```

So, this is the script I run using both functions, but I'm getting different ssim values for the same 2 pictures, and I'm not sure why.

```
img_1=*numpy array of shape (64,128,1)*

img_1_plot=255-(img_1*255)
cv2.imwrite( "img1.jpg", img_1_plot)
img1_github=cv2.imread('img_1.jpg')


img_2=*different numpy array of shape (64,128,1)*

img_2_plot=255-(img_2*255)
cv2.imwrite( "img2.jpg", img_2_plot)
img2_github=cv2.imread('img_2.jpg')


ssim_me=ssim_mine(img_1,img_2)
ssim_git=ssim_github(img1_github,img2_github)
print("mine= "+str(ssim_me)+ " & theirs= "+str(ssim_git))
```

EXAMPLE IMAGES AND SCORES:
The images below gave the following output:
"mine= 0.3959305372432932 & theirs= 0.4617707940302295"
And, they consistently give different values. Anyone have any ideas why?

[image]